# Can't connect to Local Websocket from Androidphone

Tags: python, dart, websocket

The Following Line enables my websocket server:

```
async with websockets.serve(handle, "0.0.0.0", 8765)
```

when connecting from the same Device

```
python3 -m websockets ws://192.168.178.20:8765/
```

It works flawlessly.

Now in my flutter App Though:

```
final channel = WebSocketChannel.connect(
    Uri.parse('ws://192.168.178.20:8765/'),
  );
```

it does not connect and the Websocket is null. I also did test it via a websocket-client android app.
There I get back the Error Code `1006`. Can it be that Android enforces a secure connection and this is the reason why it can't connect? I've no other device here to test it, unfortunately

Btw. I made sure that 192.168.178.20 is the device address in my home-network

Comment: Remember that your Android device has to be connected using wifi for this to work at all.  If you're using data, then it is not inside your firewall.

Comment: It's in the same Network

Answer (score 0):

on Android you need to declare the use of the internet in the Android manifest, see https://docs.flutter.dev/development/data-and-backend/networking

Comment: Thanks I'll look into this one!